# "un-register" a doParallel cluster

Tags: r, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

If I run `foreach... %dopar%` without registering a cluster, foreach raises a warning, and executes the code sequentially:

```
library("doParallel")
foreach(i=1:3) %dopar%
  sqrt(i)
```

Yields:

```
Warning message:
executing %dopar% sequentially: no parallel backend registered
```

However, if I run this same code after starting, registering, and stopping a cluster, it fails:

```
cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)
stopCluster(cl)
rm(cl)
foreach(i=1:3) %dopar%
  sqrt(i)
```

Yields:

```
Error in summary.connection(connection) : invalid connection
```

Is there an opposite of `registerDoParallel()` that cleans up the cluster registration?  Or am I stuck with the ghost of the old cluster until I re-start my R session?

/edit: some googling reveals the `bumphunter:::foreachCleanup()` function in the [bumphunter](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/bumphunter.html) Biocondoctor package:

```
function () 
{
    if (exists(".revoDoParCluster", where = doParallel:::.options)) {
        if (!is.null(doParallel:::.options$.revoDoParCluster)) 
            stopCluster(doParallel:::.options$.revoDoParCluster)
        remove(".revoDoParCluster", envir = doParallel:::.options)
    }
}
<environment: namespace:bumphunter>
```

However, this function doesn't seem to fix the problem.

```
library(bumphunter)
cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)
stopCluster(cl)
rm(cl)
bumphunter:::foreachCleanup()
foreach(i=1:3) %dopar%
  sqrt(i)
```

Where does foreach keep the information on the registered cluster?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using stopCluster(cl) after the foreach() op? The forks should be closed then and there's no need to remove the cl object.

Comment: @Patrick McCarthy Usually that is what you'd do, yes.  The point is, after the fork is closed, `foreach` is still looked for the stopped cluster.

Comment: Maybe I'm not following you right. The intended behavior is to run `foreach` after the cluster is stopped, or against your wishes the cluster stops prematurely before `foreach` finishes, or something else? Rereading, you want it to run, but with a warning, in the event the cluster is stopped?

Comment: @Patrick McCarthy I'd like return to foreach running with a warning, rather than an error after the cluster is de-registered.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The only official way to "unregister" a foreach backend is to register the sequential backend:

```
registerDoSEQ()
```

This makes sense to me because you're supposed to declare which backend to use, so I didn't see any point in providing a way to "undeclare" which backend to use. Instead, you declare that you want to use the sequential backend, which is the default.

I originally considered including an "unregister" function, but since I couldn't convince myself that it was useful, I decided to leave it out since it's much easier to add a function than to remove one.

That being said, I think all you need to do is to remove all of the variables from `foreach:::.foreachGlobals` which is where foreach keeps all of its state:

```
unregister <- function() {
  env <- foreach:::.foreachGlobals
  rm(list=ls(name=env), pos=env)
}
```

After calling this function, any parallel backend will be deregistered and the warning will be issued again if `%dopar%` is called.

Comment: Maybe adding an alias for `registerDoSeq` -> `unregister` would be the way to go?

Comment: This is a great solution as I have been dealing with this issue for nearly two years without finding a solution. I do have a question however, if I register this function, do I then run "unregister" in a single line by itself before I run the foreach loop, or do I put this in or even after the loop? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
    cl <- makeCluster(2)
    registerDoParallel(cl)
    on.exit(stopCluster(cl))
```

This worked fine for me.

Comment: If you run `stopCluster(cl)` and then try to run `%dopar%`, it will fail.  You need to run `registerDoSEQ()` first.

Comment: I guess on.exit() takes care of it.

Comment: on.exit() executes stopClusters(cl) only after %dopar% is done using the parallel backend registered by registerDoParallel(cl)

Comment: `on.exit()` basically means `stopCluster` never gets called during your session.  I needed a way stop the cluster *and then keep running `%dopar%` code*