# Error in summary.connection(connection) : invalid connection

Tags: r, logistic-regression, r-caret

Having an issue while running a logistic regression model using caret::train().
`LR = caret::train(Satisfaction ~., data= log_train, method = "glm", preProcess = c("scale"), family="binomial")`

keep getting the following line of error:

> Error in summary.connection(connection) : invalid connection

This error seems new to me as when i had previously run this code, i did not see any issue.
Please help!

Comment: This might be an issue due to your `caret` package, try updating your package and see if that helps

Comment: what if it happens in Kaggle notebooks too?

Answer (score 34):

I got this error because of an issue with the parallel computing back-end for foreach/dopar.  You may have some parallel computing going on in the background that is not getting cleaned up fully between runs.  The easiest way I have found to fix it is to call this function:

```
unregister_dopar <- function() {
  env <- foreach:::.foreachGlobals
  rm(list=ls(name=env), pos=env)
}
```

This function is from Steve Weston's accepted answer in this thread:
["un-register" a doParallel cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097729/un-register-a-doparallel-cluster)

Comment: This is a great solution as I have been dealing with this issue for nearly two years without finding a solution.  I do have a question however, if I register this function, do I then run "unregister_dopar" in a single line by itself before I run the foreach loop, or do I put this in or even after the loop?  Thanks!