# Error in summary.connection(connection) : invalid connection when running GeoLift example

Tags: r

I am working through https://github.com/ArturoEsquerra/GeoLift/blob/master/vignettes/GeoLift_Walkthrough.md and getting error message: Error in summary.connection(connection) : invalid connection. when I try to execute the following:

```
resultsSearch <- GeoLiftPower.search(data = GeoTestData_PreTest,
                                     treatment_periods = c(15),
                                     N = c(2,3,4),
                                     horizon = 50,
                                     Y_id = "Y",
                                     location_id = "location",
                                     time_id = "time",
                                     top_results = 20,
                                     alpha = 0.1,
                                     type = "pValue",
                                     fixed_effects = TRUE,
                                     ProgressBar = TRUE)
```

I have tried the solution here: [Error in summary.connection(connection) : invalid connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64519640/error-in-summary-connectionconnection-invalid-connection), but it hasnt resolved the issue.

Any ideas / solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding parallel = FALSE in the GeoLiftPower.Search parameters.